# How to remove amount of volume added to cumulative volume in the past based on condition

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

In this code, if Volume > 10 mil, I start to add the volume to Cumulative volume and we create a line below the candle which extend until current bar,  so volume > 10 mil , we create a line and cumvol += volume.

However, I want to subtract volume associated with the line if the price broke the line ( Low < y value of line).

I tried to track the line and its volume but it never subtract any volume from it.

here is part of the code:

```
float yValue = na
int x1 = na
int x2 = na

L100x = close * (1 - 0.005)
var float cumLvol = 0.0
var arr = array.new_line(50)     
var arrVolume = array.new_float(50) 
var float lineVolume = 0.0

// condition to start adding to cumulative
if volume > 10000000
    x1 := bar_index 
    x2 := bar_index
    yValue := L100x
    array.push(arrVolume, Lvol)
    cumLvol += volume

// if line brokes we reduce the volume
for i = array.size(arr) - 1 to 0 by 1
    yValue := line.get_y1(array.get(arr, i))
    lineVolume := array.get(arrVolume, i)
    if low < yValue
        cumLvol -= lineVolume

// Plot the cumulative Lvol
plot(series=cumLvol, title="Cumulative Lvol", color=color.blue)
```

not sure what's wrong with it.